# Deploy on Heroku django app psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation " tableName " does not exist

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-migrations

I'm deploying my django project on **heroku** and my db is on **postgresql** , however, when i open the app on heroku doesn't show me a particular template called "products.html". So , i checked the logs and it's showing me an error of psycopg2 and the relations im my models and views associated to that template .

I makemigrations/migrate locally , updated the git repo , pushed to heroku and migrate it on heroku, but none of these things works .

In addition , when i run heroku run manage.py migrate , it tells me there are no migrations to apply.

[No migrations to apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GSrT.png)
Can anyone suggest me something please?

````
2019-03-21T22:43:30.822852+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.51.203.60 - - [21/Mar/2019:22:43:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202942+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /petit/productos
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202960+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202963+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202964+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202966+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "product" does not exist
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202968+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ..."product"."k_idcommerce", "product"."v_price" FROM "product"
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202969+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202971+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202972+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202973+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202974+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202976+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202978+00:00 app[web.1]: response = get_response(request)
2019-03-21T22:43:39.202979+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response ```
````

Comment: did you run  `manage.py makemigration` makemigration before running migrate on heroku

Comment: @webDev, there's no reason to run `makemigrations` on Heroku. By the time code gets deployed there should be no model changes that would result in a new migration. Create migrations locally and apply them to the local database, then on Heroku just apply them.

Comment: Are you sure you committed all of your migrations before deploying? Try running [`python manage.py showmigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations) locally and compare its output to `heroku run python manage.py showmigrations` on Heroku.